# Add ToolTip of Empty Text to TextBox in C# WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

I'm trying to add a ToolTip to textbox to show it when the text input is empty in TextChangedEvent,
I have tried this solution from this post [How add and show tooltip textbox WPF if textbox not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925113/how-add-and-show-tooltip-textbox-wpf-if-textbox-not-empty)

```
 <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But I got this error :

> Error  A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'Trigger'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

How can I fix this problem ?

***Update:***

In addition, I would like to implement something like that ( without MVVM pattern ):

[image]

*Source*: [Facebook Website](http://www.facebook.com)

Comment: The code you showed is working.
The error is somewhere else.
It will be better if you give a minimal example that is guaranteed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The code is working, in the sense that it does not throw exceptions.
But logically ... he does something completely incomprehensible.
You are comparing a ToolTip to a string.
But these are different types!
The comparison will always be false.

Comment: I forget to set the `Tooltip` property

Comment: "I would like to implement something like that ( without MVVM pattern )" - You will most likely need to use data validation.
It will be extremely difficult to do this without MVVM.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't have used MVVM pattern

Comment: The problem is that many WPF tools are much more difficult to use outside of MVVM.
In this case, you need to validate the data entering the Data Context.
To do this, the data type needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo interfaces. By implementing them in the Data Context, you are actually creating a ViewModel.
Without this, you will have to create your own ValidationRule or even a set of them for each element.
Such an implementation would be much more complex and difficult to use.

Comment: And I would advise you to create a new topic to continue your question.
Conditional ToolTip output (this topic) has nothing to do with validating multiple items and outputting validation results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand what kind of logic you want to implement.
From my guess, this is to show the ToolTip only when the line is empty or, on the contrary, do not show it for empty.

Here are both fully working options.

```
        <Style  x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

```
        <Style  x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Using:

```
    <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Now , Thank you it works , but could you please tell me how can achieve this on button click event , I would like to show this tooltip every time when textboxes are empty, I have many textboxes?

Comment: Then you need a Popup, not a ToolTip.
The ToolTip is only shown when the mouse cursor is over the element.
And it’s not clear what you want to implement.
So that when you click on the button next to the button, a window pops up with information about which TextBox are empty?
Or did such a window pop up beside each empty TextBox?